# Name expected in kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am getting an error and im not sure why, I've tried a few different solutions ive found online and nothing has worked.

```
@Database(entities = {Tea.class}, version = 1, exportSchema = false)
```

the error im getting is that "Name expected" for after {Tea/class}

```
package com.google.developers.teacup.data

import android.content.Context
import androidx.room.Database
import androidx.room.Entity
import androidx.room.RoomDatabase
@Entity
@Database(entities = {Tea.class}, version = 1, exportSchema = 
false)
abstract class TeaDatabase: RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun teaDao(): TeaDao

    companion object {

    @Volatile
    private var instance: TeaDatabase? = null

    /**
     * Returns an instance of Room Database
     *
     * @param context application context
     * @return The singleton TeaDatabase
     */
    fun getInstance(context: Context): TeaDatabase {

    return(instance!!)}
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure that `@Entity` is added on top of `Tea.class`

Comment: It is, @Entity is one line above the line I posted my question for, i also imported androidx.room.Entity, I am not sure what the "Name expected" should be, it is saying it needs to be after the }and before the comma,

Comment: Can you please add code for Entity class.

Comment: Made an edit to add full code

Comment: Please add code for `Tea.class` and Please add `@Entity` on top of `Tea.class`, remove `@Entity` from top of  `TeaDatabase` class

Answer (score 3):

As per Kotlin syntax, you need to replace `Tea.class` with `Tea::class`

```
@Database(entities = {Tea::class}, version = 1, exportSchema = false)
```

Remove `@Entity` from your `TeaDatabase` class and add it to `Tea.class`.

Hope it should solve your problem.

Comment: Is it working? If yes, don't forget to accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Entities is supposed to be an array, so in Kotlin it should be defined with [], meaning your @Database line should be:

```
@Database(entities = [Tea::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
```

(bearing in mind what Shailendra Madda said about using `Tea::class` instead of `Tea.class`)